# Unity3D C#: Drawing border of a hexagon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im fairly new to both Unity or C# or even anything GUI connected but im trying to make a simple hexagonal grid, i followed this tutorial: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/procedural-hexagon-terrain-tutorial.233296/ and it created nice chunks of hexes. Now the thing is i'd like to make a borderline for each hex. I tried to use ToonShader but it doesn't seem to work with such structure. I also tried to make a LineRenderer in every hex, containing coordinates of it's edgepoints, but after some lurking I realised that I should probably use 6 LineRenderers for each hex. Here comes my question, does using so many LineRenderers makes any sense? Is there any more convinient (I'm sure there is) or prettier way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: draw the outline into the tile graphics

Answer (score 0):

LineRenderer supports more than one line, :) so you need only 1 LineRenderer per hex. You can do this:

```
LineRenderer lineRenderer = ... ; // Add or get LineRenderer component to game object
lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(7);  // 6+1 since vertex 6 has to connect to vertex 1
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    Vector3 pos = ... ; // Positions of hex vertices
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, pos);
}
```

Though this might be not very efficient depending on how many tiles you have. If you have a lot of them, but not too many, you could create a single LineRenderer for all tiles. And if you have really lots of them, then subdivide the map into regions containing X x Y tiles, and generate one LineRenderer per region. Also notice that adjacent hexes can share lines if you go with those methods.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind spending about $20, [Vectrosity](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/vectrosity-fast-and-easy-line-drawing.49941/) is a nice Unity plugin that allows you to draw lines. I used it in a graph drawing application that I made with Unity to draw vertices between nodes.